# 1.14 PS4 Minecraft cannot tame ocelot

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I can take the cats that are already non-ocelot (Cats in villages or witch hut) but when I try to tame the ocelots I stay still, and they come to me and I feed them like normal but after 2-3 fish, it shows hearts but the ocelot stayed an ocelot? I tried again with another and same thing.

Comment: This is probably the seventh ocelot taming duplicate I've seen so far. If you search "ocelot" in the searchbar you will get lots of answers. Do any of them work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Ocelot Wont Tame In The Windows 10 PC Version](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/342341/the-ocelot-wont-tame-in-the-windows-10-pc-version). The update changes are mentioned there as well.

Answer (score 0):

With the new Minecraft 1.14 update, ocelots no longer turn into cats by feeding them fish.
I am unsure if you can make them into cats in a different way, but not by feeding them fish.

Answer (score 0):

In the new Minecraft 1.14 Snapshots, the item "raw fish" and the other types of fish no longer exist, therefore making it impossible to tame ocelots. Instead, there is a new mob called the "Cat" added into the game. I am not sure how to tame a cat, but I know for sure that ocelots can no longer be tamed.