# What happens if your ocelot cannot spawn into a cat

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When ever I would try to tame it for hours and hours waiting my time the ocelot would never ever turn into a cat.So I kept trying to do it by looking it up on the internet but it still did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you provide a bit more information? Things like phone, minecraft version and what you have tried

Comment: Are you using raw fish, what version of bedrock are you using?

Comment: [Related, possible dupe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/342341/the-ocelot-wont-tame-in-the-windows-10-pc-version)

Answer (score 3):

## Ocelots can no longer be tamed

In bedrock version 1.8+, and java edition 1.14+, ocelots are no longer tamable. You will need to find stray cats, which spawn near villages, to tame them as a pet.

Excerpt from the [minecraft wiki page,](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_1.8#Mobs_2)

> - Ocelots

- Can no longer be tamed.
- The player can still feed them to gain their trust.
- Ocelots can now be fed pufferfish and tropical fish items.

Also,

> - Stray cats

- Spawn in villages.
- Can be tamed using fish.
- Bring gifts to the player.
- Have dyeable collars, like dogs.