# How do I tame an ocelot in minecraft P.E version 1.9.1?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have tried taming an ocelot and there is no raw fish even in the creative inventory. When I feed it other fish, it only goes into breeding mode but hasn’t been tamed. Is this a bug in the update? Because 1.9.0 worked perfectly fine...

Comment: As of [1.8](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Ocelot) ocelots can no longer be tamed

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/342341/the-ocelot-wont-tame-in-the-windows-10-pc-version/342345#342345)

Answer (score 1):

As Ben said, you can't tame ocelots anymore as of 1.8.

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot#Trust):

> A player can feed an ocelot raw salmon or raw cod to gain its trust. Prior to Java Edition 1.14, Bedrock Edition, and PlayStation 4 Edition, feeding an ocelot could tame it, but in current editions feeding an ocelot causes it to trust the player, after which it no longer flees from the player.

If you want a cat, you need to [tame a cat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cat#Taming) (a mob added in 1.8 and spawns in villages):

> Stray cats can be tamed using raw cod or raw salmon.